# Suckerfish dropdown not working in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, suckerfish

This is a weird bug that I can't figure out because I have tested it on my PC in IE7 and IE8 on XP and it's working just fine.

But the main navigation is broken in XP on this site:

http://tupelomainstreet.com/play

I've attached screenshots of my client's screen and environment.

If anyone has any black magic for IE, that would be amazing. I'm at a loss.
[image: client's screen]

[image: client's environment]

Comment: Does the page validate for the `DOCTYPE` you're using? Is the browser in `Quirks Mode`?

Comment: Double click the small yellow triangle at the bottom left, what does it say in the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On http://tupelomainstreet.com/shop/salons-and-spas:

You're loading these JavaScript files from **your server**:

- `<script src="js/libs/modernizr-1.6.min.js"></script>`
- `<script src="js/mylibs/fancyzoom.js"></script>`
- `<script src="js/mylibs/slideshow.js"></script>`
- `<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>`
- `<script src="js/script.js"></script>`
- *(for `lt IE 7` only)* `<script src="js/libs/dd_belatedpng.js"></script>`

Let's stick with `modernizr-1.6.min.js`.

If I [*load that file*](http://tupelomainstreet.com/shop/js/libs/modernizr-1.6.min.js), I get something which looks distinctly *not like* a JavaScript file:

```
<!doctype html>  
...
<title>Downtown Tupelo Main Street Association</title>
```

The fact that a HTML page is being returned is surely the work of `mod_rewrite`. Without `mod_rewrite`, I'm sure you'd be getting a nice, easy to debug `404 Not Found` error instead.

I believe the easiest way to fix this is to prepend the script includes with `/`:

```
<script src="/js/libs/modernizr-1.6.min.js"></script>
```

This will load [*the correct file*](http://tupelomainstreet.com/js/libs/modernizr-1.6.min.js).

It's a very safe bet that this problem is what's killing your menu in Internet Explorer.

Comment: The heck are you talking about.  That looks like a javascript file to me :(

Comment: Actually I'm rather surprised it works in any browser with those incorrect script links... firefox shows html on the .js page, how's it working :p

Comment: Hahaha, I was being sarcastic :(

Comment: It was interesting because I was using firefox's source viewer which let's you follow the src= link to the new file.  It didn't appear to change which confused me so I kept clicking.  I ended up on `http://tupelomainstreet.com/shop/js/libs/js/libs/js/libs/js/libs/modernizr-1.6.min.js` and this is the entire contents on the page:  `<p>Error: The URL contains too many segments.</p>`  How cryptic!

Comment: You should have wrote "Yeah I agree, that reeeeeeally looks like a JavaScript file!" or similar. Then I'd have caught the sarcasm :) Edit: yeah, I clicked that too, just to see how many times it would let me. Curiosity!

Comment: Hey guys, a little more info on this, I'm using Expression Engine on this site and it's a little weird how Expression Engine handles routes, so I think that's what's causing the issues. I think I have it fixed now, but I'm gonna have to wait until my client takes a look tomorrow to know for sure because I can't recreate this error on my test machine. I'm actually surprised it was working on every browser I tested too.

Comment: It's not fixed. Now *[the site](http://tupelomainstreet.com/)* is broken in more browsers (IE, Chrome, possibly others, only seems to work in Firefox). *[This path, for example](http://tupelomainstreet.com/js/libs/modernizr-1.6.min.js)* does not exist. I don't know *anything* about Expression Engine, so I can't help you with that. All I know it that it's not fixed right now.

Comment: Hey everyone, I think I have it fixed now and it was definitely a problem with how the js files were getting linked that thirtydot pointed out on this thread. So thanks a bunch.

Comment: I agree, I think you've fixed it now.